# Is drilldown supported for embedded powerbi dashboards?

Tags: azure, powerbi-embedded

We are evaluating the integration of Azure PowerBI visuals with our web application, and need to provide drill-down capability from the dashboard summary view (item count by category) to a list view (item list per category) to a detailed view (details on the item).

Is this currently supported?

Comment: Are you embedding a Dashboard, a Tile or a Report? Are you trying to drill from an embedded Dashboard to a report?

Comment: I'm trying to understand whether i will be able to drill down from my summary view to the next two levels of detail. Im uncertain of Azure PowerBI terminology/definitions at this point. Can I leverage a powerbi report or a powerbi dashboard in some way, and will I be able to support drill down? Whatever it takes, as long as I can meet my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported to "drill down" from an embedded dashboard to a report or another tile.

So, you could embed a report. Then, you could drill down, use slicers, etc. The embedded Power BI Report works exactly the same if it was Power BI web app.